# Как менять 5 фрагментов по одной кнопке, кнопка реализована в майн активити?

Tags: android

NextButton = findViewById (R.Id.NextbButton);

NextButton.setOnClickListener
public void (View view) {

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransact ion().replace(R.Id.container_FL, new Second_Fragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Меняйте в транзакции не один, а все пять.